# jQuery .hover on future elements

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, hover

I have a jsFiddle set up here that i want to work on future elements that will be injected into the DOM via AJAX etc:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nb3uW/5/

How would i go about converting this over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the docs on [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live)? That should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry.Should have thought of that.  Assumed hover would not work with .live() method.  Have updated here - http://jsfiddle.net/Nb3uW/6/

Comment: I have forked this here http://jsfiddle.net/SBhnc/1/ with some adjustments.  Sometimes it exhibits very strange behaviour though where it renders very slowly.